# WordPress Custom Post Type Event with custom permalink structure

Tags: events, permalinks, custom-post-type

I need some help about Custom permalinks for custom post types.

I have created a custom post type called "evento" and 3 custom fields for storing date, month and year of the events.

I would like to have a permalinks structure like this:

```
/eventos/2012/07/30
```

... where the standard structure would be:

```
/?post_type=evento&ano=2012&mes=07&dia=30
```

How to make this magic happen in WordPress? I do not know much about .Htaccess =(

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

RewriteRule ^eventos/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ /?post_type=evento&ano=$1&mes=$2&dia=$3 [L]

I tested it using http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!!!! =)

```
add_action('init', 'evento_add_rewrite_rules');
function evento_add_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ){
    // Add day archive (and pagination)
    add_rewrite_rule("eventos/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?",'index.php?post_type=evento&ano=$matches[1]&mes=$matches[2]&dia=$matches[3]&paged=$matches[4]','top');
    add_rewrite_rule("eventos/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/?",'index.php?post_type=evento&ano=$matches[1]&mes=$matches[2]&dia=$matches[3]','top');

    // Add month archive (and pagination)
    add_rewrite_rule("eventos/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?",'index.php?post_type=evento&ano=$matches[1]&mes=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]','top');
    add_rewrite_rule("eventos/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/?",'index.php?post_type=evento&ano=$matches[1]&mes=$matches[2]','top');

    // Add year archive (and pagination)
    add_rewrite_rule("eventos/([0-9]{4})/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?",'index.php?post_type=evento&ano=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]','top');
    add_rewrite_rule("eventos/([0-9]{4})/?",'index.php?post_type=evento&ano=$matches[1]','top');
}
```

Thanks!